# .then() resolves itself before internal promise resolves

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

I have a promise chain that calls the function pngQuant

```
.then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    pngQuant.pngQuant(testObj['pngquant']);
}, err =>console.log(err))
//Then upload images
.then(response => {console.log(response)},err=>console.log(err));


function pngQuant(JSON){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        var execString = "find " + pathresolve('./src/resizer/tmp/') + " -name '*.png'"
        execString += " -exec " + pathresolve('./lib/pngquant') + " --force --ext=.png";

        exec(execString,(err,stdout,stderr)=>{
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                reject(stderr);
            }

            else{
                console.log("resolved");
                resolve("Compression Complete");
            }

        })
    });
}
```

However the second 'then' in the chain resolves itself and console logs 'undefined', and then immediately after, the console log in the pnqQuant function gets called, meaning that the then is resolved before the pngQuant resolve function is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return statement was causing an issue.

```
.then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    pngQuant.pngQuant(testObj['pngquant']); 
}, err =>console.log(err))
// then upload images
.then(response => {
  console.log(response);
}, err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 1):

Return the `promise` created by calling `pngQuant` from the first `then`:

```
.then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    return pngQuant.pngQuant(testObj['pngquant']); // we returned the promise from pngQuant
}, err =>console.log(err))
// then upload images
.then(response => {
  console.log(response);
}, err => console.log(err));
```

Check the [doc of `then` here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

Comment: Sorry, this is a snippet of my code, pngquant is defined earlier as follows

const pngQuant = require('./pngquant');

Comment: @TomN did this work? If so, please mark it as the answer or do post the correct answer yourself.

Comment: I resolved this by changing the first line to just a call to the pngquant function rather than putting a console log before hand